# Are there any JQuery plugins to allow uploading a file without refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery

Are there any JQuery plugins to allow uploading a file without refreshing the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, check out jquery form

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following. It supports drag n drop upload, too. Though the Windows 2003 support seems a bit wonky for changing styles.

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Answer (score 0):

Check this list: http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2010/02/13/7-trusted-ajax-file-upload-plugins-using-jquery/

Most of them use either 2 techniques, a hidden IFRAME element or uploading via a hidden SWF (Flash file).

- Christian